# C++ Building Parse Tree with Boost and Modern C++

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, compiler

I am writing a parser. To build up the tree, I need to find the correct type for my node based on text from my language input file. Right now, I have a map from a string (the node name) to a factory function which returns the correct type. Is there any way I can make this more simple/idiomatic when calling make shared?

Anything else I can do more idiomatically or with a better architecture is appreciated too.

abstract_node.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

namespace ql::parser {
    class AbstractNode : protected std::enable_shared_from_this<AbstractNode> {
    public:
        typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractNode>> ChildrenRef;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<AbstractNode> ParentRef;
    protected:
        ChildrenRef m_Children;
        ParentRef m_Parent;
    public:
        explicit AbstractNode(ParentRef parent) : m_Parent(std::move(parent)) {}

        void addChild(std::shared_ptr<AbstractNode> const& node);
    };
}
```

abstract_node_with_descriptor.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <parser/node/parse_node.hpp>

namespace ql::parser {
    class ParseWithDescriptorNode : public ParseNode {
    protected:
        std::string_view m_InnerBody;
    public:
        ParseWithDescriptorNode(std::string&& body, std::string_view const& innerBody, std::vector<std::string>&& tokens, ParentRef const& parent)
                : ParseNode(std::move(body), std::move(tokens), parent), m_InnerBody(innerBody) {
        }
    };
}
```

parser.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

#include <parser/node/master_node.hpp>
#include <parser/node/structure/parse_with_descriptor_node.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

namespace ql::parser {
    class Parser {
    private:
        using NodeFactory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<ParseWithDescriptorNode>(std::string&&, std::string_view const&, std::vector<std::string>&&,
                                                                                   AbstractNode::ParentRef)>;

        std::map<std::string, NodeFactory> m_NamesToNodes;

        template<typename TNode>
        void registerNode(std::string_view nodeName) {
            // TODO use forwarding?
            m_NamesToNodes.emplace(nodeName, [](auto&& block, auto const& body, auto&& tokens, auto parent) {
                auto node = std::make_shared<TNode>(std::forward<decltype(block)>(block), body, std::forward<decltype(tokens)>(tokens), parent);
                node->parse();
                return node;
            });
        }

        std::shared_ptr<AbstractNode> getNode(std::string const& nodeName,
                                              std::string&& blockWithInfo, std::string_view const& innerBlock, std::vector<std::string>&& tokens,
                                              AbstractNode::ParentRef parent);

        void recurseNodes(std::string_view code, std::weak_ptr<AbstractNode> const& parent, int depth = 0);

    public:
        Parser();

        std::shared_ptr<MasterNode> parse(po::variables_map& options);

        std::shared_ptr<MasterNode> getNodes(std::string code);
    };
}
```

parser.cpp

```
#include "parser.hpp"

#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim_all.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/erase.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

#include <util/read.hpp>
#include <util/terminal_color.hpp>
#include <parser/node/structure/package_node.hpp>
#include <parser/node/structure/def_func_node.hpp>
#include <parser/node/structure/impl_func_node.hpp>

namespace ql::parser {
    Parser::Parser() {
        registerNode<PackageNode>("pckg");
        registerNode<DefineFunctionNode>("def");
        registerNode<ImplementFunctionNode>("impl");
        registerNode<ParseWithDescriptorNode>("default");
    }

    std::shared_ptr<MasterNode> Parser::parse(po::variables_map& options) {
        auto sources = options["input"].as<std::vector<std::string>>();
        std::string sourceFileName = sources[0];
        std::cout << sourceFileName << std::endl;
        auto src = util::readAllText(sourceFileName);
        auto node = getNodes(src.value());
        return node;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<AbstractNode> Parser::getNode(std::string const& nodeName,
                                                  std::string&& blockWithInfo, std::string_view const& innerBlock, std::vector<std::string>&& tokens,
                                                  AbstractNode::ParentRef parent) {
        // Check if we have a generator function that can make this requested node, or else use default
        auto it = m_NamesToNodes.find(nodeName);
        NodeFactory& nodeFactoryFunc = it == m_NamesToNodes.end() ? m_NamesToNodes["default"] : it->second;
        // Give ownership of copied code slice to this node. View of inner block still references original memory since we move it instead of copying
        auto node = nodeFactoryFunc(std::move(blockWithInfo), innerBlock, std::move(tokens), std::move(parent));
        return node;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<MasterNode> Parser::getNodes(std::string code) {
        auto parent = std::make_shared<MasterNode>();
        boost::remove_erase_if(code, boost::is_any_of("\n\r"));
        recurseNodes(code, parent);
        return parent;
    }

    void Parser::recurseNodes(std::string_view code, std::weak_ptr<AbstractNode> const& parent, int depth) {
        auto level = 0;
        auto blockInfoStart = 0ul, blockStart = 0ul;
        for (auto i = 0ul; i < code.size(); i++) {
            char c = code[i];
            if (c == '{') {
                if (level++ == 0) {
                    blockStart = i + 1ul;
                }
            } else if (c == '}') {
                if (--level == 0) {
                    auto blockInfoSize = i - blockInfoStart + 1ul;
                    std::string blockWithInfo(code.substr(blockInfoStart, blockInfoSize));

                    // Split by tabs and spaces into tokens, which we use to find what type of node to create
                    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
                    auto deliminator = boost::is_any_of("\t ");
                    boost::split(tokens, blockWithInfo, deliminator, boost::token_compress_on);
                    // Remove first and last blank tokens if they exist
                    boost::trim_all_if(tokens, [](auto const& token) { return token.empty(); });

                    std::string const& nodeName = tokens[0ul]; // TODO do more checks as opposed to just taking first
                    std::cout << KGRN << std::setw(7) << nodeName << RST << " → " << blockWithInfo << FBLU("#") << std::endl;

                    // Find inner block
                    auto blockContentStart = blockStart, blockContentSize = i - blockContentStart;
                    std::string_view blockContents = std::string_view(blockWithInfo).substr(blockContentStart - blockInfoStart, blockContentSize);
                    std::cout << blockContents << FRED("$") << std::endl;
                    auto child = getNode(nodeName, std::move(blockWithInfo), blockContents, std::move(tokens), parent);
                    // Add children to parent node, parent node is owning via a shared pointer
                    parent.lock()->addChild(child);

                    // Recurse on the inner contents of the block so that each node added is for one block only
                    recurseNodes(code.substr(blockContentStart, blockContentSize), child, depth + 1);
                    blockInfoStart = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractNode` must have a virtual destructor (if we have child classes, we'll be deleting them from a pointer to the base class).

---

It doesn't look like we require shared ownership of nodes, so we don't need to use `std::shared_ptr`. The parent node owns its children, and children have a non-owning pointer to the parent.

We can therefore use `unique_ptr` for storing the children, and a raw pointer to refer to the parent. This makes the code quite a bit simpler.

---

For "sink" arguments (function arguments that we want to copy and store internally), it's best to take them by value. The current code requires r-value references, [which would force the user to do a copy themselves outside the class](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/08/21/c-sink-parameter-passing/) if they don't want to move something, which is very awkward.

So we should be doing:

```
    ParseWithDescriptorNode(std::string body, std::string_view innerBody, std::vector<std::string> tokens, ParentRef parent)
            : ParseNode(std::move(body), std::move(tokens), std::move(parent)), m_InnerBody(std::move(innerBody)) {
    }
```

(There's no point moving the `string_view`, but it's consistent, and there's no real downside).

---

Since we specify exact types here:

```
    using NodeFactory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<ParseWithDescriptorNode>(std::string&&, std::string_view const&, std::vector<std::string>&&, AbstractNode::ParentRef)>;
```

It's kinda weird to use a generic lambda here:

```
        m_NamesToNodes.emplace(nodeName, [](auto&& block, auto const& body, auto&& tokens, auto parent) {
            auto node = std::make_shared<TNode>(std::forward<decltype(block)>(block), body, std::forward<decltype(tokens)>(tokens), parent);
            node->parse();
            return node;
        });
```

I guess the generic lambda is to get perfect forwarding working, but it's a bit confusing.

As above, the specification of `std::string&&` and `std::vector<std::string>&&` unnecessarily require r-value references, which isn't ideal.

---

```
    std::string_view m_InnerBody;
```

We need to be careful about keeping a `string_view` around as a class member. It looks like this will refer to a local variable in `recurseNodes`, which will go out of scope and become invalid well before the Node's lifetime ends. There are two things we could do to improve things:

Do everything we need to do with the string data in the constructor (i.e. call `parse()` in the constructor, instead of as a separate step).

Store indices instead (since an index remains valid and usable independent of the lifetime of the string).

---

(Unlike the other answer) I personally like the use of `auto` for declaring local variables. It makes declarations instantly recognizable and uniform, and puts the focus on the semantics of the object (value, `&`, `const&`), instead unnecessarily repeating the type.

We can improve things a bit though:

- Use `auto` consistently for every local variable.
- Put `const`ness after the `auto`, so `auto` is always the first word.
- Put the type on the right-hand side of the declaration if necessary.
- Never declare multiple variables in one line using commas.

e.g.

```
    auto sources = options["input"].as<std::vector<std::string>>();
    auto const& firstFile = sources.front();
    ...
        auto c = char{ code[i] };
    ...
                auto blockWithInfo = std::string(code.substr(blockInfoStart, blockInfoSize));
```

---

Using `boost` is fine, but it may be worth writing our own split function using `std::string_view`. It looks like we could do all the parsing without any string copies at all.

Answer (score 3):

**Maintainability**
You may be the only programmer on this project, but if you work on larger projects other people may have to maintain the code. Code like this:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
```

makes the code much harder to maintain. That is especially true when that code is in a header file such as `parser.hpp`.
The previous code is the equivalent of putting

```
using namespace std;
```

into a header file. How is someone that has to maintain the code going to find it? In 3 years even you may not remember this was done.

**Portability**
While

```
#pragma once
```

is widely supported, it has never been added to the C++ programming standard. Therefore there may actually be compilers that don't implement it. To ensure a header file is only included once it may be better to use

```
#ifndef H_HEADER_NAME
#define H_HEADER_NAME

/* contents of header */

#endif /* H_HEADER_NAME */
```

because this will always be portable.

**Abuse of auto**
C++ is a **typed language**, not a **scripting language**. The `auto` type declaration is very useful, especially in ranged loops, however, declaring almost every variable in a function as `auto` is an abuse of the feature. for maintainers of the code it might be better if most of the type declarations in `void Parser::recurseNodes(std::string_view code, std::weak_ptr<AbstractNode> const& parent, int depth)` used explicit type declarations rather than `auto`.

Comment: @Zeta 1) Is there anything else you don't like in the answer. 2) I can remove the iterator section completely, but I'm not going to refactor the code. The entire function is a key portion of a recursive descent parser and some of the data types in the function aren't clear.

Comment: @Zeta done, no more iterator section.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments. I do see now how I abused the `auto` keyword. My original intention was to use it only where you can interpret the type based on what is being assigned. An example would be like the result of `make_shared<Type>` since it can be easily seen there. Or with `0ul`, type is unsigned long. I guess CLion has spoiled me there. I used the namespace using since it is what is demonstrated in the [Boost docu](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp337609360), I was just trying to make it less verbose.

Comment: Also, `namespace po = boost::program_options` is a bit different from `using namespace std` because in the latter all functions/stuff is opened up to the global namespace, which could cause more potential collisions versus just `po`. I guess the idea was that many code editors now have a click to follow, so people could easily see that it maps to `boost::program_options`.